# How can I get full path to directory where was package installed by bower

Tags: continuous-integration, bower

I'm installed some packages from *bower*.
For tests i need full path to directory with one of the installed packages.

How can i get this path (something like *$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR* on travis-ci)?

In *Programmatic API* i don't find nothing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue i decided to use [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/).
I needed to *SpecRunner.html* from [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) that's to run tests.

Due to GruntJS (and plugin [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jasmine)) i can set nessesary paths (sources, specs, helpers) one time - in Gruntfile:

```
jasmine: {
  pivotal: {
    src: 'src/**/*.js',
    options: {
      specs: 'spec/*Spec.js',
      helpers: 'spec/*Helper.js'
    }
  }
}
```

For dynamically include libs, loaded from [bower](http://bower.io/), i used GruntJS's plugin [grunt-bower-install](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bower-install).

Also for getting path to package, you can use path from *.bowerrc*:

```
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('.bowerrc'),
build: {
  src: 'src/<%= pkg.directory %>.js'
}
```